# Setting ringtone volume on pause is being ignored

Tags: android

In our app, we need to keep the ringtone volume to 10% of max volume. In my activity's `onResume` event, I store the original volume and change the value to 10% of max. Later, when `onPause` event is received, I restore the value to the original.

This logic seems to work fine on most devices. However, on Samsung devices, the behavior is a bit strange.

When "show all apps" button is tapped (the bottom left square box), `onPause` event is called as expected. At this point, I can see on the device that the ringtone volume is indeed restored. However, after "close all app" button is tapped, the ringtone volume that I just restored gets reversed. I am back to 10% ringtone volume.

Basically, if I kill the app, I am left at 10% ringtone volume (although my last API call had restored to the original volume).

Wondering if anyone has any insight on what could be going on. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some code that downgrades volume to %10 of max volume in the onDestroy() or onStop() sections of your app.
If you don't have any code regarding this issue, you might add some code to adjust the volume to any % you want when the app is killed. I think, by defining the volume level in onDestroy() or onStop() will fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do have the restore logic in onDestroy as well. However, onDestroy is never invoked when the app is killed (via close all).

Comment: Then maybe you should create a never ending service(doesn't stop by 'close all app') that controls volume level.